# Not able to update the spyder-kernel

Tags: spyder

It says

**Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.0.1 and < 2.1.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
You can install it by running it in a system terminal:
conda install spyder‑kernels=2.0
or
pip install spyder‑kernels==2.0.***

Then I get this error: https://trialblogme1234.blogspot.com/2021/06/not-able-to-update-spyder-kernel.html, and nothing works.

Comment: You can also try to run `conda update anaconda` before running `conda install spyder-kernels=2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the installation again but requesting a more specific version of `spyder-kernels` (something like `conda install spyder-kernels=2.0.1`.

If the error regarding conflicts persist you could try to create a new environment and install the latest spyder release available (which in turn will install the correct `spyder-kernels` version). Using the `conda-forge` channel, you could create a new environment running something like this from the Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda create -n spyder-cf -c conda-forge spyder
```

Then to run the spyder installed in that environment:

```
conda activate spyder-cf
spyder
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,

The code worked with no errors and seemed like everything has been installed but the spyder console was still not accessible popping up with the same message - "Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.0.1 and < 2.1.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you. You can install it by running it in a system terminal: conda install spyder‑kernels=2.0 or pip install spyder‑kernels==2.0.*"

Comment: I think there was an issue related to that message: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15787 which will be fixed in the next release (5.0.4). You can check here if the new version is released to do the update: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me. Running Spyder gives the output:

Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the matplotlib module installed or it occurred a problem importing it. Due to that, it is not possible for Spyder to create this special console for you.

Spyder is now in the spyder-cf environment.
So ran "conda install matplotlib" in that environment.

Spyder is now working (for now).